# Ml Kit text recognition not downloading model in Android

Tags: android, ocr, firebase-mlkit, text-recognition, google-mlkit

As the title says, I tried the demo app offered by Google and it keep showing a Toast with this message "Waiting for text recognition model to be downloaded", and I got this error in the console:

"E/Vision: Error loading module com.google.android.gms.vision.ocr optional module true: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0."

I tried many solutions but no one worked for me this is the solutions I tried:

- Update Google Play Services app.
- Adding this in ManifestFile:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.******.***"
  android:installLocation="auto">

<application>

  ...

  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ocr"/>

</application>
```

- Check Internet connection.
- Check storage for free space.
- Clear Google Play Services data.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you provide your Google Play Service version number?

Comment: 20.42.14 Beta I tried the previous one and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

20.42.14 should be a good version as of today. Note that optional module download takes some time. It is expected to see these logs in the initial launch of your app.
Clearing Google Play Services data cleans all downloaded modules which may delete your module if it has already been downloaded. Have you tried to reboot your phone to see if it works?

A bug report sent to mlkit-feedback@googlegroups.com would be helpful for us to diagnose this further. Thanks!

Comment: I tried everything none worked, I will try to provide bug report as soon as I can, Thanks.